# Writing a response containing an array of elements in a nodejs application

Tags: html, node.js

I want to write some html code in a nodejs application when the user requests. I want to show the array elements on the page as the following code:

```
const http = require('http');

const port=3000;

http.createServer((req, res)=>{

    const {url , method , headers} = req;

    res.write(`<html>
                 <head>
                    <title>My yest</title>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                     <h1>This is my h1</h1>
                     <p>
                        This is my first paragraph. The request method and url are: ${method} , ${url}
                     </p>
                     <p>
                        The items: 
                           <span>
                           ${[1, 2, 3].forEach((el)=>{
                              {el};
                           })}
                           </span>
                     </p>
                 </body>
               </html>`);
    res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

But the following code does not work as I desire. I want the array elements to be shown in the second paragraph.Whats wrong and how may I do that? I don't want to use view engine for it.

```
   <span>
      ${[1, 2, 3].forEach((el)=>{
       {el};
        })}
   </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) the value of `${foo}` is replaced by the result of evaluating the expression `foo`.

The [return value of `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) is `undefined` so `${[1, 2, 3].forEach((el)=>{{el};})}` gives you nothing.

(Aside from that, `(el)=>{{el};}` gives you nothing anyway).

You probably want to use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead.

```
${[1, 2, 3].join("")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way :

```
 <span>
      ${[1, 2, 3].map((el)=>el).join("")}
   </span>
```

Comment: That's an exceptionally pointless use of `map`.

Comment: Thanks. I used `${[1,2,3].map((el)=>el).join("</br>")}`

Comment: @Javad-M – The map is pointless. The `br` element has a mandatory start tag and a forbidden end tag. You're using the forbidden end tag and not including the mandatory start tag!

Comment: ok changed to `<br>`